# Python and FFMPEG video streaming not displaying via HTML5

Tags: python, sockets, ffmpeg, html5-video, chunking

I'm trying to write a python script to serve a video over HTTP and display it via HTML5 video tag, I'm using FFMPEG to serve the video over HTTP and receiving the the video via sockets in Python. FFMPEG seems to be sending the video and my Python script is receiving it but for some reason I'm not able to display it in my web browser nor getting any visible error in my script.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

This is the FFMPEG line I'm using to send the video to HTTP

```
FFMPEG -re -i video_file.webm -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -f h264 http://127.0.0.1:8081
```

Here is my Python code

```
import socket   #for sockets handling
import time     #for time functions
import sys

hostIP = '127.0.0.1'
SourcePort = 8081 #FFMPEG
PlayerPort = 8082 #Internet Browser

def gen_headers():
     # determine response code
     h = ''
     h = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n'
     # write further headers
     current_date = time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
     h += 'Date: ' + current_date +'\n'
     h += 'Content-Type: video/mp4\n\n'
     return h

def start_server():
    socketFFMPEG = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    # this is for easy starting/killing the app
    socketFFMPEG.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    print('Socket created')

    try:
        socketFFMPEG.bind((hostIP, SourcePort))
        print('Socket bind complete')
    except socket.error as msg:
        print('Bind failed. Error : ' + str(sys.exc_info()))
        sys.exit()

    #Start listening on socketFFMPEG
    socketFFMPEG.listen(10)
    print('Socket now listening. Waiting for video source from FFMPEG on port', SourcePort)

    conn, addr = socketFFMPEG.accept()
    ip, port = str(addr[0]), str(addr[1])
    print('Accepting connection from ' + ip + ':' + port)

    socketPlayer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    socketPlayer.bind((hostIP, PlayerPort))
    socketPlayer.listen(1) #listen just 1 petition
    print('Waiting for Internet Browser')
    conn2, addr2 = socketPlayer.accept()
    conn2.sendall(gen_headers().encode())

    while True:
        try :
            #receive data from client FFMPEG
            input_from_FFMPEG = conn.recv(1024) 
            #send data to internet browser
            conn2.sendall(input_from_FFMPEG)
        except socket.error:
            print('Error data :' + str(input_from_FFMPEG))
            print('send Error : ' + str(sys.exc_info()))
            conn2.close()
            sys.exit()

    socketFFMPEG.close()

start_server()
```

I'm getting the error 10053 "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine" when loading the following "byte" type data

```
\x00\x00\x00\x01A\x9b\x1dI\xe1\x0f&S\x02\xbf\xb1\x82j3{qz\x85\xca\\\xb2\xb7\xc5\xdfi\x92y\x0c{\xb0\xde\xd1\x96j\xccE\xa3G\x87\x84Z\x0191\xba\x8a3\x8e\xe2lfX\x82\xd4*N\x8a\x9f\xa9\xc9\xfb\x13\xfc_]D\x0f\x9e\x1c"\x0fN\xceu\t\x17n\xbe\x95\xd1\x10Wj\xf5t\x90\xa8\x1am\xf7!d\x82py\n\x10\xf5\x9b{\xd9\xf8\x8e^\xc7\xb3o+\x0eQX\xb3\x17B?\xb8\x1c\xecP\xa0\xf10\xc7\xc8\x8d\xf1P\xd3\xdf\xd0\xd5\x13ah+bM\x9c\xbe\xca\xb4\x9a?\xac\xb9\x0fao\xf3\xed\x9c\xe4^\x10\x079t\xf4\x0f\xce\xbe*\xd4w\x1f\x1a\x02\xbd\xed\xe9\x16\x8a\x98\xe0\x1d\xc4\xde5\xa8\xf0\x88\xb4\x07=\xe2w\xc3Q\xc1\x99K7\xff\x01`(\xb3sN\x88\x18\xfd7\xd4\x07\xab\x95\xf95\x05\xcd\xd6,!=\xfb\xc4\xc8\xbf\xad\x96\x83\xc0\x9b%\xdds\x92s\xc0lN\xdd\x14\xba\xbd\x04L\xb1\x08\xec[~tB~`\r\xbe\xa9\xbe\xa4r`\xa3\x98\x19z\xa9\xe9\xd3jK>(\xd5\x8c\x9eY~\xa8\x9f\x86\x90\x148R\xfd<\xb2\xdaUy\xa8\xb5\xba\x1d\xd1\xf6\xa6N\xb0#\x08Xo\xa6\x1c \xbaB\x8cbp\x1c\r\xa1\xa4"\x06\xd8\xe5\x85[\x89\x8a\xcba\xa3\xcc\xe0C\x946\xad6\x08\x90\r&\xcb\x13\xa6\xfbG\xc5\x85I<\x96\xcb\x89}\xcb\xda\xa5\x02\xbcB\xb9\x93\x938\x89\x1c\x92\xb3\x83\xfe\xa7\xf6\xa8\x1f\xdf\xa8\xef\xd55\xb6\xbf>#\xba\xd7\x8e\xd2z\xc2\xca\xf9\xdd2\xdd\x96\xb6\xf8\xc3\xc1\x0f/D\x05\xd3?\x18\xb1\x85T\x08\xcd\xfc\xc7p\xba\x0c\x93\xcdY\xf3 !4\x13\xaen\x82\x10[\x07I>\xe4\xc3\xb7\xca\xee\x93\r\xc3\xe1>\xe9\xd6\x9a\xbeLQ\x93\x86n\xadb\x13\xcas\xc0\xdeh\x1a\x9f\x00Dp\x94fv\xb7\xd9\xba\x93\x0c\xd1H2\x0e\xa2]`\xf2Q{+o\x80\xf0\x8a\x11"\x94u\x9b1\xc3\xdaV\xd9\x9e\xc6\xf7?\x18\xd9\xfbs\xf3\x07\xc6\x91\x83\x19\'\x13\xe4o\xa9S\x1cP\xa4w\xbc\xe36\xb9k\xc3\xaa":~`\xe7\x18\xe8\x9bu\n\x16\xf3\x89\xe2k\x07\x08\xf6\x8c\x98\x98\xbd\x8f*\x11\xe7\xa1\nj1\'\xe2=\x7f\xdf\x16\xc8\xf6\xec\xe1\xe6G\xd1\x1b\xeb\xc0\xd4\xf7\xc3c\xc7v\xc3\xf8\xa5\xac\x89\xdd4\x90i\t\x98\xfe\xfcx\xad{[\xf4\x92\x16^O\xf2\xc2]\xec\xa7\xe9Gu\\dF\xa6\xa7\xd3k?\xba\xedY\xba\x85\'\x1a\xa6.(\xcfB\x82tN\xdc\xad\xe6\xfcM\x01:\x0b\x14\x070\xf4\x99l2C\x92\x9c\x13h\x82\xf6w\xc4$5\xe1~\x11T~\xc9\x8f\xaeUAI%\xa6\x12(\x9c\x17\x9d*\xcc9\xee\xb7\xb8w \x92\x9a\x1cD\xfd\xd8wi7rt\xd8\x93\xbd7\x83\xf1\xe3\xbd\x92\x81\xe0\xfel\xfa\\\x9c\xebM\xf3m`p\xb9\xe2\x13Kd\xe08\xcc\x15\x96[G\xda`\x8cD\xa7\xf1\xd3\xc8T\xcf\xb1)\xa5E$\x91\x94{\x88&\xac\xc1\x92\xd5E\xa98\xd2\x89\xd1?\xd7\x9c\xdc\xbb!\x18\xc1\xa1m\xba*L\xab\xa0\xff\xd8\xee\xbbH\xe3\xa2\xe4\x9d=9\x05\xb4\x9bm\xe7\xc6J\xd9\xc3\xb1\xe9b*jB`4t\x9fv\xe8\xc4F\x9c`\xd0\x03\xd8\x12}\x8b\xb3$A\x9c\xdc;\x81@)rH\xf1\x18\xe1\xba\x0c4\x06\xe9xa\x94\xdd\xde\xa8&\xef)\xd7F\x94F\xa7j\xd3\x13O\xe03\xc9\xc9\xf2\x15\x1a\x9bsy\x16\x83H\xb4\x9e\xee\xc9M\xe7\xf4x \xa5\x9c^\xb9m\xeee\x03=_\x11\xda^l\xfe\xba\xa4\x98mjW\xf0\xa9\xc4\x11g\xd9C\xf7K.\x8c\xab3~n%\x7f\xc0p\xc8\xb1\xd6\x8d\xe5E\xb1\xc1\xe3(~\x9e\x9c\x91.\xdc\x08\xfb\xa0\xbe\x98y$U\xdeH\x08\xb2z,yX\xfaqx\xfe\xb0\xa9\xb4Q\xf2P\x95d\xc8\x88\r\xc3\x1dr\x88\xba\xc8\x990`(\x08m\x19\xebi\xf8\x11\xc6g\xd6\xc4\x12C\xad~\xe1$2\x01Hmg\xdb\x920\x18\xcc\xc0K\x04~\x1e\xeb\xd9>\x81F*I\x99\xe4\x00\xa3\xc4,U\x89\xdf\x843\xa3\xfb\xea\xc9d\x05\xeb]
```

Answer (score 0):

With this line:

```
conn2.sendall(gen_headers().encode()+input_from_FFMPEG)
```

your code repeatedly sends the HTTP headers once for every 1024 bytes of video. You only need to send the headers once after the GET request is received. Then send the body which will be the video data.

Also, read the request before replying: conn2.recv(1024). I've found this to be necessary, however, I am not using Windows.

One other thing, The HTTP headers are supposed to be separated by `\r\n`, not just `\n`, so try changing that if the above doesn't fix it.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but now I'm getting the 'error 10053 ' - 'An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine'
I'm sending the header just before the 'while True:' line and sending the received data inside the loop.

Comment: @arussell: updated answer with some more suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to play the video using the webm format with your suggestion about the header.
I changed the python code and the FFMPEG line to serve an MP4 video and now I'm getting the same 10053 error.
can you tell me how to implement this "read the request before replying: conn2.recv(1024)" or tell me what else to do in order to have more information about the error or solve it.

Comment: I just edited the python code and the FFMPEG line for mp4 and added the byte type data where I'm getting the error.